# Change color of HTML element based on previous value - CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to change the `background-color` of an element in HTML using CSS when the element is hovered on. Here is what I have:

```
h1 {
    background-color: rgb(100,60,0);
}

h1:hover {
    /* increase background-color red component by 50 */
    /* new background-color would be rgb(150,60,0) */

}
```

I can't figure out how to achieve that.

Also, I have seen some suggestions online about doing it with LESS or SASS but I would really prefer a pure-CSS solution.

Thank you very much.

Comment: LESS or SASS would allow you a pure CSS solution... They are just compilers for CSS.

Comment: It sounds like you're asking this because the CSS will be modified at some point after the page has been loaded by something other than CSS, in which case you'll have to use javascript.

Comment: You can do this with JavaScript. I would suggest using this handly JavaScript color manipulation library: http://bgrins.github.io/TinyColor/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't add logic or function in a CSS like you would do in other programming langages. If you want to do so, you need a CSS pre-processor like Sass or LESS that will generate the CSS result. 
But you have to know that LESS or Sass will generate normal CSS (as you said pure CSS) because they are CSS. It's like a CSS extension...

For exemple with Sass:

```
$color: rgb(100,60,0);
h1 {
    background-color: $color;
  &:hover {
    // increase background-color red component by 50
    // new background-color would be rgb(150,60,0)
    background-color: adjust-color($color, $red: 50);
  }
}
```

will generate following CSS

```
h1 {
  background-color: #643c00;
}
h1:hover {
  background-color: #963c00;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I will definitely look into that

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a CSS solution but this should work(untested) as required. The second listener is for changing the colour back, so you can remove it if you don't need it =)

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('h'); 
//get all elements with h tag
for(var i = 0; i< elements.length;i++)
{
    var element = elements[i];
    element.addEventListener("mouseenter", function() //adds event listener for mouse moving onto element
    { 
        var currentBGColor = getComputedStyle(elements[i])['backgroundColor']; 
        // gets current background color
        var parts = currentBGColor.replace(/[a-z|(|)]/gi,'').split(','); 
        //removes rgba( & ), then cuts string by comma
        elements[i].style.backgroundColor = 'rgba('+parseInt(parts[0]+50)+''+parts[1]+''+parts[2]+''+parts[3]+')'; 
        //set new style
    }
    element.addEventListener("mouseleave", function() //adds event listener for mouse leaving element
    { 
        var currentBGColor = getComputedStyle(elements[i])['backgroundColor']; 
        // gets current background color
        var parts = currentBGColor.replace(/[a-z|(|)]/gi,'').split(','); 
        //removes rgba( & ), then cuts string by comma
        elements[i].style.backgroundColor = 'rgba('+parseInt(parts[0]-50)+''+parts[1]+''+parts[2]+''+parts[3]+')'; 
        //set new style
    }
}
```